# Error message when I try search one Wiki on IBM Connections

Tags: ibm-connections

When I try search for one wiki on IBM connections, the following message is displayed:

> The search was not performed because the server could not be contacted

The server is running normal. Do I have a problem with indexing?

Answer (score 2):

Is the Search application running? Can you navigate to http: //server:port/search ?
This type of error is generally displayed when the Wikis front-end can't communicate with the Search API service.